# Removed XX rows containing missing values (lower value than expected?)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Has anyone come across a "Removed XXXX rows containing missing values" in which the value is **lower** than expected? I have more points out of the range than what the warning is giving me.

I have a large dataset (63000 rows) with more than 7000 values lower than 24, which is my lower y-axis limit but get the message saying it is only ~3000.

I haven't seen any info on it anywhere, so would appreciate if anyone who has had this problem before can tell me why this is happening. Thanks!

Here is now a simpler example provided by @JonSpring in his comment:

```r
ggplot(data.frame(X2 = 1:5, X3 = c(30, 31, 20, 40, 41)), aes(X2, X3)) + 
geom_point() + 
geom_line() + 
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(25, 50))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, user22483480! I understand completely that you cannot share the actual data, though that does not release you from the expectation of providing something. Please try to create a representative dataset or use a public dataset and find limits/options that evidence the same warning you're seeing there.

Comment: For some discussions on how to provide sample data (e.g., `dput`, `data.frame`, `read.table`), please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Sorry, you are absolutely right. I think I managed to provide an example. Hope this is enough.

Comment: Sorry, I was new and this went closed fast. As an update, I think it may have something to do with geom_line() still plotting part of data. When I use geom_point() instead, I get the right numbers. If anyone could still comment anyway, I'd be grateful.

Comment: That's a good example, looking at it @user22483480

Comment: @Mark, please consider reopening with the recent edit (and I can reproduce the issue).

Comment: Possibly coincidence, but `summary(d$X4 < 24 & lead(d$X4) < 24 & lag(d$X4) < 24)` is also 2, so I wonder if the reporting for `geom_line` observations excluded is based on looking at whether the point and the adjacent points on either side are also within range.

Comment: Smaller example confirming that the filtering warnings for `geom_line` are not straightforward. Your example doesn't need theming, secondary axes, x limits, extraneous columns and layers, or more data points than we can grok at a glance. Here I have five points, middle one out of range, so two of the four lines not plotted -- with no warning of any missing. `ggplot(data.frame(X2 = 1:5, X3 = c(30, 31, 20, 40, 41)), aes(X2, X3)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(25, 50))`. This produces `Warning message:
Removed 1 rows containing missing values ('geom_point()'). `

Comment: I think this is an area for potential improvement, so I have entered an issue for ggplot2 here: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5405

Comment: Yes, you are right - thanks! Sorry for overdoing the example, at first I had no idea where the problem was and secondary axis variable was the one giving me trouble, thought it could be the transformation. Will make it simpler next time :) Thanks again!

Comment: @r2evans thanks for that! :-) also thanks OP for adding code + data to your question

Comment: The best way to say "thank you" would be to go back and simplify your example to the one proposed by @JonSpring: then the question would be simple and self-contained, and the answer could just point out that it's complicated.

Comment: Maybe `geom_line` only warns if *both* endpoints of a segment are missing?

Comment: I thought so, but that's not it. (Or at least that's not all of it -- I tried adding more out-of-range points in the middle of my example and it didn't trigger a warning.)